# Select N rows from a table with a non-unique foreign key

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780236/limit-the-return-of-non-unique-values) before and while the answers I got were spectacular I might need to clearify.

Just like [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104971/sql-query-help-selecting-rows-that-appear-a-certain-number-of-times) I want to return N number of rows depending on a value in a column.

My example will be I have a blog where I want to show my posts along with a preview of the comments.  The last three comments to be exact.

I have have I need for my posts but I am racking my brain to get the comments right.  The comments table has a foreign key of post_id which obviously multiple comments can be attached to one post so if a post has 20 comments then I just want to return the last three.  What makes this somewhat tricky is I want to do it in one query and not a "limit 3" query per blog post which makes rendering a page with a lot of posts very query heavy.

```
SELECT *
FROM replies
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT( post_id ) <=3
```

This query does what I want but only returns one of each comment and not three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  post_id,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    replies li
                WHERE   li.post_id = dlo.post_id
                ORDER BY
                        li.post_id, li.id
                LIMIT 2, 1
                ), CAST(0xFFFFFFFF AS DECIMAL)) AS mid
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT post_id
                FROM    replies dl
                ) dlo
        ) lo, replies l
WHERE   l.replies >= lo.replies
        AND l.replies <= lo.replies
        AND l.id <= lo.mid
```

Having an index on `replies (post_id, id)` (in this order) will greatly improve this query.

Note the usage of `l.replies >= lo.replies AND l.replies <= lo.replies`: this is to make the index to be usable.

See the article in my blog for details:

- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/) (how to select `N` rows from a table for each `GROUP`)

Comment: I'll definitely have to do some reading to figure out what is going on here.  Some of this query, especially the CAST() is beyond my scope.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is a constant which containt maximal possible INTEGER. Since it has type BINARY, CAST converts it to an integer. MID is the 3rd id for a given group, or a MAXINT if there is no 3rd.

Comment: You can replace the whole CAST(...) thing with a constant 4294967295 if it confuses you :)

Comment: Ah yes, 4294967295, now it makes sense.  :)

Comment: @TheLizardKing: Doesn't it look round to you? :) You can use 4,000,000,000 if you're sure you will never have such a big ID in your database :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you track comment date?  You can sort those results to grab only the 3 most recent ones.

Comment: That's true but I would need to grab 3 of the most recent ones per post_id.  If I have 15 comments and 3 posts, 5 comments a post then I would want a query that would return 9 comments.  3 of the most recent comments for each post_id.

Answer (score 0):

following ian Jacobs idea

declare @PostID int

```
select top 3 post_id, comment
from replies
where post_id=@PostID
order by createdate desc
```